# Converting Array Values from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 for JSON Encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I receive a response from a web service, and the values are ISO-8859-1 encoded. The supplied library converts the response to an array, and I am using `json_encode` to serialize the response and store it in the database. It's a MySQL database, InnoDB engine, with a UTF8 character set.

The encoding issue revealed itself by this warning in my log:

```
PHP Warning:  json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in...
```

I know the array key values are alright because they're always the same and I don't see the warning for every request.

Is there any downside to using `array_map` with `utf8_encode` to get rid of the warnings?

```
json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode', $response))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will anyway need to call it systematically. So go for it.